# htaccess : url rule with text or text/number

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Users should be redirected to :

```
mywebsite.com/index.php?section=$1&subsection=$2
```

The rewrited URL could be :

```
mywebsite.com/profile/john-doe
```

or

```
mywebsite.com/profile/john-doe-52
```

So I thought the right rule would be :

```
^([-/$a-z]+)\/([-/$a-z0-9]+)$
```

But it seems that if **mywebsite.com/profile/john-doe-52** works well, when **mywebsite.com/profile/john-doe** doesn't do the job.

What don't I understand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^/?([^\.*]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&subsection=$2 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/([-$a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?section=$1&subsection=$2 [L,QSA]
```